# I can only go to Object Mode

Tags: modeling

I can't go to Edit Mode or any other mode besides Object Mode.

Can someone help me out? It won't show any other mode besides Object Mode.

Comment: have you selected an object and pressed tab?

Comment: Hi! What did you try so far?
Do you have this problem with more files or just one?

Comment: can you share some screen shot

Answer (score 1):

There are mainly two ways to switch between Object and Edit mode.

### 1. TAB

- As @depperm suggests you need to have at least one object selected;
- you also need to have the mouse pointer inside the 3D View window;
- just press TAB to switch.

### 2. Mode menu

- In the 3D View header you'll find a mode menu (see picture below);
  [image]
- just click on it and select the mode you want to switch to.